# axios copy data from one collection or api to another

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, axios

I would like to know if there is a better way to copy data from an api collection to another.Basically I would like to get data from one collection and post it in another collection

I am looking for a better way to do it than I correctly doing

get from collection A

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "614d3cedfb2600340fdb28f9"
    },
    "date": "2021-09-23",
    "title": "First test",
    "description": "Going",
    
}
```

I like to post in collection b

```
return await axios
    .get(url.rest_api + '/template', {
      params: {
        owner: 'abc123',
      },
    })
    .then(response => {
        axios
        .post(url.rest_api + '/todos', response.data)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.warn(error.message);
            })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: It would be better redirect internally to different routes, or use some middleware to perform common task

Comment: You can send any object to axios. If the response of first request is exactly what the second request needs, just use it. If not, create it!